# Objective C block property is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to learn more about Objective C blocks and how they work. I've set up a simple project with two UIViewControllers embedded in a UINavigationController in Storyboard. I'm attempting to change the background color of the first ViewController's view from the second view controller. Here's some code:

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController{
    ColorBlock _colorBlock;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"theSegue"]){
        SecondViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
        vc.colorBlock = _colorBlock;
    }
}

- (IBAction)moveToSecondViewController:(id)sender {
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    _colorBlock = ^{
        [[weakSelf view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    };
}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
typedef void (^ColorBlock)(void);

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (readwrite, copy) ColorBlock colorBlock;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(self.colorBlock){
        self.colorBlock();
    }
}
```

The first ViewController's background color isn't being changed because in the `buttonTapped:` method of SecondViewController.m, `self.colorBlock` is nil, causing the block invocation not to be called. I thought I had successfully set the block in `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Why is my block property nil?

Comment: are you sure moveToSecondViewController: is called (and called before prepare for segue?) pls double check with a breakpoint in both.

Comment: Yes `moveToSecondViewController:` is called and my `_colorBlock` ivar is successfully set. Then, `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called and the ivar is successfully set onto SecondViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `prepareForSegue`, the destination has already been instantiated. So assuming that `SecondViewController` is the destination, you can do:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"theSegue"]){
        SecondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSAssert([vc isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]], @"destination is not SecondViewController class");
        vc.colorBlock = _colorBlock;
    }
}
```

Comment: @danh No, he's instantiating a new copy of SecondViewController. Thus, he's setting a property in some phantom VC that he's not segueing to.

Comment: oh. good catch. yes, this should do it. i was seeing what i was expecting in the code, not what was there. (though I think the assert is a little too defensive)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that `destinationViewController` property. That solved it!